# Play One Frame Per Second with Opencv Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

There is a 30fps video with 2 hour playback time. I just need one frame per second to be played. I can do the following by -

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.avi')
count = 0
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if count%30==0:
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    count = count+1
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the mentioned method is very slow and not feasible. I am trying to do something that will make a list of frame number to show (each 30th frame = 30,90,120,150,.....) then only access those frame and play. I have written the following codes -

```
import cv2

# read the video and extract info about it
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vid.avi')


# get total number of frames and generate a list with each 30 th frame 
totalFrames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
x = [i for i in range (1, totalFrames) if divmod(i, int(30))[1]==0]


for myFrameNumber in x:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,myFrameNumber)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("video", frame)

        # something wrong in the following three line
        ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1)
        if ch == 27:
            break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code only plays the 30th frame while the "esc" button pressed otherwise it plays at a normal speed. Can anyone please figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are locked in the `while True:` loop until you press escape. The `while` has the code to display video normally, continually reading and displaying frames. But when you press escape the code exists to the `for myFrameNumber in x:` block which set the next frame in the array with frame numbers.

You should remove the `While` loop, so only the frames you `set` are read and displayed. To achieve a second delay, you can increase the wait time in `waitKey` (in milliseconds)

```
    for myFrameNumber in x:
            #set which frame to read
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,myFrameNumber)
            # read frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            # display frame
            cv2.imshow("video", frame)

            # wait one second, exit loop if escape is pressed
            ch = 0xFF & cv2.waitKey(1000)
            if ch == 27:
            break
```